# Eloquent ORM conditional model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

My schema is as follows:

```
courses
 -id
 -title
 -...

documents
 -id
 -...

videos
 -id
 -path
 -...

course_resources
 -id
 -course_id
 -type [docs OR videos]
 -resource_id
```

Every course resource can be of multiple types, in this case documents or videos. How should one write the relationship in order to retrieve either the document or the video based on the **type** column in the **course_resources** pivot table? Obviously the **resource_id** can take either the value of **video_id** or of the **document_id**.

Ideally I would like something like this:

```
$course=Course::with('resources')->find(1);
foreach($course->resources as $resource){
 //check resource type
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Many-to-Many Polymorphic Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) to accomplish this. Your `course_resources` table structure is almost right, you need however to replace it with this table, so that Laravel can understand the relation and fetch the correct resources:

```
| coursable        |
|------------------|
| course_id        |
| coursable_id     |
| coursable_type   |
```

First you need to have three models for `Course`, `Document` and `Video`. Then you need to add the polymorphic relations to the `Course` model:

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Document', 'coursable');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'coursable');
    }
}
```

Now you can do the following to access resources, no more conditions needed to differentiate them:

```
// Eager load both relations
$course = Course::with('documents', 'videos')->find(1);

// Iterate over documents
foreach($course->documents as $document) {
    // ...
}

// Iterate over videos
foreach($course->videos as $video) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks or „Dau o bere!” :)

Comment: Buna traducerea :)). Cu placere.